# I cannot get a .pdf file generated by most Beamer themes to print using Adobe. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: beamer

I created my lecture notes using the CambridgeUS theme. My students cannot get the .pdf file to print from Adobe. I tried printing my notes from Adobe on two different printers and I get the following message: "The document could not be printed, kindly use our help page to troubleshoot." Adobe's help page didn't solve my problem. Other pdf files print fine to these same printers, and I have had no issues so it isn't the printers. I have tried every theme in beamer and have no trouble printing the same notes if I use Boatilla or the default theme. Thankfully, I have a work around. However, I am still wondering what I am getting wrong or missing when I use CambridgeUS theme. And advice, insight? TIA.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you test to print a very minimal example with this theme? If the problem goes away then you can start to comment out page by page and see when the problem goes away (and then maybe piece by piece on that page, if possible).

Comment: I've heard similar stories before, e.g. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62748193#62748193 and following comments. I never managed to reproduce the problem myself, but my best guess is that it is connected to the shadows. Might be related to https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/824

Comment: Hi mickep, Printing a very minimal example (a one pager) was a great idea. I tried printing the title page  and it wouldn't print.

Comment: Can you print a page which does not have a shadow?

Comment: Does the following print? `\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=white}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}`

Comment: Yes! samcarter it print

Comment: @BarbaraKuzmak Thanks for checking! In this case I think the source of the problem is https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/824